# How to get the date based on "N" value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Reference to the below sample table(TABLE_REFERENCE), I need to arrive the "Last_reprice_date" & "Next_Reprice_date" based on the value_date & reprice_in_years

Below I have calculate in excel level (Last_reprice_date & Next_Reprice_date)
How can I get this in Ms SQL server ?

I tried using datediff & dateadd not getting the expected output

```
SELECT A.*,
DATEADD(year,datediff(year,value_date,reporting_date),value_date)
FROM TABLE_REFERENCE A
```

```
reporting_date | Unique_No| Value_Date|Reprice_in_years|Last_reprice_date|Next_Reprice_date    
2023-06-30| 198123456A|2022-01-25|1|2023-01-25|2023-01-25    
2023-06-30| 237519821C|2015-11-13|5|2020-11-13|2020-11-13    
2023-06-30| 987187315R|2021-03-12|2|2023-03-12|2025-03-12    
2023-06-30| 891284311M|2021-06-23|1|2023-06-23|2024-06-23    
2023-06-30| 917900915F|2015-12-22|5|2020-12-22|2025-12-22    
2023-06-30| 878711126L|2016-05-13|0.5|2023-05-13|2023-11-13    
2023-06-30| 842145117Y|2021-08-18|2||2023-08-18
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! a sample input and output would be appreciated.

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: The question is unclear (try adding another table expected results based on the provided data, and **do no use screenshots for technical information!**), but most likely you want a Windowing Function: possibly first_value or last_value. Or maybe even just a GROUP BY.

Comment: Also, the big reason not to use screenshots is these problems are easier if we have an actual table to work with in our own server or at a site like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), to be sure the solution works. If you have a screenshot, we have to RETYPE all that data... and _most people won't do that_. They'll move on to another question, meaning **you won't get an answer at all**. But if we can copy/paste your data, without retyping, it goes MUCH quicker for us, and we're more likely to spend a few minutes to look at your problem. If you want help, make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Added the table without the image format

Comment: Input data : reporting_date | Unique_No| Value_Date|Reprice_in_years output require : Last_reprice_date|Next_Reprice_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done it in Excel, It's basically the same formula in SQL.

Since your reprice period column can be a fraction of a year, you need to convert them to month and calculate the years like so:

```
select * 
  , case when floor(datediff(month, value_date, reporting_date) / (Reprice_in_years * 12) ) = 0 then null 
  else dateadd(month, floor(datediff(month, value_date, reporting_date) / (Reprice_in_years * 12) ) *  Reprice_in_years * 12 , Value_Date) end as Last_reprice_date
  , dateadd(month, floor(datediff(month, value_date, reporting_date) / (Reprice_in_years * 12) ) *  Reprice_in_years * 12 +  Reprice_in_years * 12, Value_Date) as Next_Reprice_date
from  TableName
```

| reporting_date | Unique_No | Value_Date | Reprice_in_years | Last_reprice_date | Next_Reprice_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-30 | 198123456A | 2022-01-25 | 1.00 | 2023-01-25 | 2024-01-25 |
| 2023-06-30 | 237519821C | 2015-11-13 | 5.00 | 2020-11-13 | 2025-11-13 |
| 2023-06-30 | 987187315R | 2021-03-12 | 2.00 | 2023-03-12 | 2025-03-12 |
| 2023-06-30 | 891284311M | 2021-06-23 | 1.00 | 2023-06-23 | 2024-06-23 |
| 2023-06-30 | 917900915F | 2015-12-22 | 5.00 | 2020-12-22 | 2025-12-22 |
| 2023-06-30 | 878711126L | 2016-05-13 | 0.50 | 2023-05-13 | 2023-11-13 |
| 2023-06-30 | 842145117Y | 2021-08-18 | 2.00 | *null* | 2023-08-18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tV-fEt9l)